# Как отображать нужные мне компоненты

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компонент TaskList в нем отрисовывается несколько Task . Задача - отрисовывать по клику разные обьекты массива. Что мне закидывать в state? Правильно понимаю что как раз массив?И как его изменить в таком случае?

собственно вот код

компонент Task

```
class Task extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { name, description, group } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {statementsData.map(elem => (
          <article
            style={{
              border: "2px solid blue ",
              padding: "30px",
              margin: "3px"
            }}
            key={elem.id}
          >
            <div>{elem.name}</div>
            <div>{elem.description}</div>
            <div>{elem.group}</div>
          </article>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Task.defaultProps = {
  group: "Execute"
};

export const statementsData = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "first",
    description:
      "нализируйте день: выясняйте, что помешало выполнить все пункты вашего листа задач на день. По итогам решайт",
    group: "Execute"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "second",
    description:
      "Выделяйте приоритетные дела —  задачи, позволяющие достигать глобальных целей.",
    group: "Execute"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "third",
    description:
      "ййййцу йцу йцйцв йцв бальных целей. Ответьте на вопрос, насколько",
    group: "Performens"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "thirdqq",
    description: "о важная и срочная каждая задача и нельзя ли ",
    group: "Done"
  }
];

export default Task;
```

компонент TaskList

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Task from "../task/task";
import { statementsData } from "../task/task";

class TaskList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       statementsData
    };
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log(statementsData);
  }

  showAlert() {
    alert("Im an alert");
  }

  showAlertq() {
    this.setState({
        this.statementsData = []
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.showAlertq.bind(this)}>отрисовать все</button>
        <button onClick={this.showAlert}>отрисовать Execute</button>
        <button onClick={this.showAlert}>отрисовать Performed</button>
        <button onClick={this.showAlert}>отрисовать Done</button>
        <h1>hello Tasklist</h1>
        <Task />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default TaskList;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не ясен вопрос, что значит "как его изменять по значению пропса у Task"? можете конкретизировать?

Comment: Немного исправил уже код , есть продвижение но основной вопрос остался. Изменил описание. + на фото видно кнопки , а так же в каждом блоке есть пропс elem.group вот по нему и нужна сортиврока

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логично, что в состоянии компонента Tasks точно должно быть свойство, отвечающее за группу элементов, которые нужно отрендерить:

```
this.state = {
    group: null/"Performed"/"Execute"...
}
```

Далее нам нужны данные. Для этого можно (нужно) создать массив объектов, которые будут пропсами для компонента `Task` (но я дивом сделаю ниже, лень писать)

```
taskProps = [
    {
        title: "Title 1",
        content: "Lorem ipsum",
        group: "Performed"
    },
    {
        title: "Title 2",
        content: "Lorem ipsum dolor",
        group: "Execute"
    },
    ...
]
```

По нажатию на кнопку будем менять состояние state.group

```
<button onClick={() => this.changeGroup("All")}>отрисовать все</button>
<button onClick={() => this.changeGroup("Execute")}>отрисовать Execute</button>
<button onClick={() => this.changeGroup("Performed")}>отрисовать Performed</button>
<button onClick={() => this.changeGroup("Done")}>отрисовать Done</button>
```

И сам changeGroup:

```
changeGroup(group) {
    this.setState({
        group: group
    })
}
```

Теперь компоненты надо как-то фильтровать. Лучший способ - использовать метод .filter(). Он возьмет массив и выберет из него только то, что соответствует нашему условию:

```
this.taskProps.filter(item => item.group === this.state.group || this.state.group === null)
```

Теперь у нас есть отфильтрованный массив. Осталось передать его объекты в компонент `Task` в качестве проспсов, но в нашем случае понадобится еще один метод `.map`

```
taskProps.filter(item => item.group === this.state.group || this.state.group === null).map(item => (
    <div style={{ background: "gray", margin: "4px" }}> // тут типа Task
        <h2>title: {item.title}</h2>
        <span>content: {item.content}</span>
        <h3>group: {item.group}</h3>
    </div>
))}
```

Вот и все. Рабочий пример залил на [pen](https://codepen.io/misha-saidow/pen/oPXzEW) для удобства

Comment: Ты лучший бро) Спасибо,все очень подробно и понятно)